# Formatting Visio Connections in VBA

Tags: vba, visio

Is there a way to edit connections through VBA?

For example, change the line weight of a connector when running a VBA script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1() 
Dim shp As Shape, mst As Master 
' iterate all shapes per page 
For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes 
' declare parent master for current shape 
Set mst = shp.Master 
' Process only shapes that have parent master-shape 
If Not (mst Is Nothing) Then 
' change only shapes, which master-shape is dynamic connector 
If mst.Name = "Dynamic connector" Then shp.Cells("LineWeight").Formula =  "0.5 pt"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

This code set Line Weight of each connector on page to 0.5 pt

Answer (score 0):

This code changed Line Weight of selected shape

> Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
>   shp.Cells("LineWeight").Formula = "0.5 pt"